# Cycle through struct elements

Tags: c++, struct, reflection

I defined the following struct:

```
struct Color {
    unsigned int r, g, b, a;
};
```

Is there a way to cycle through its elements like:

```
Color c;

for (unsigned int i "in all struct elements") {
    c.i = 0;
}
```

So that, after that, all 4 unsigned int in `c` are set to 0?

Comment: Why don't you initialize those members in the struct?

Comment: Initialize at definition like `Color c = {};`? "Reset" using assignment as `c = {};`? Plain old setting bytes of memory as `std::memset(&c, 0, sizeof c);`?

Comment: @JVApen I don't need all variables (well, colors) of that type to be "transparent-white"! :)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thanks. Apologies... I'm a beginner and don't even have a book to follow. :\ I should.

Comment: In that case, you most likely want a constructor

Comment: @JVApen, you mean a class then? Maybe. Right now that simple struct in the example works fine. I might change it to a class later.

Comment: Struct and class are the same thing, just different behavior regarding default access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use something like

```
Color color;
color = { 0 };
```